# Progress bar only load one time

Tags: java, android

My progress bar can only use one time,when i click it second time,it likes a loop,never end,what is the problem?

```
class ProgressThread extends Thread {   

    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;
    int maxBarValue=100;
    int delay=40;

    Handler mHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;

    // Constructor with an argument that specifies Handler on main thread
    // to which messages will be sent by this thread.

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        mState = RUNNING;   
        total = maxBarValue;
        while (mState == RUNNING) {
            // The method Thread.sleep throws an InterruptedException if Thread.interrupt() 
            // were to be issued while thread is sleeping; the exception must be caught.
            try {
                // Control speed of update (but precision of delay not guaranteed)
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Thread was Interrupted");
            }

            // Send message (with current value of  total as data) to Handler on UI thread
            // so that it can update the progress bar.

            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", total);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            total--;    // Count down
        }
        total=maxBarValue;
    }


public class ProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressThread progThread;
    ProgressDialog progDialog;
    Button button1, button2;
    int typeBar;                     // Determines type progress bar: 0 = spinner, 1 = horizontal
    int delay = 40;                  // Milliseconds of delay in the update loop
    int maxBarValue = 200;           // Maximum value of horizontal progress bar

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Process button to start spinner progress dialog with anonymous inner class
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                typeBar = 0;
                showDialog(typeBar);
            }
        }); 

        // Process button to start horizontal progress bar dialog with anonymous inner class
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                typeBar = 1;
                showDialog(typeBar);
            }
        }); 
    }

    // Method to create a progress bar dialog of either spinner or horizontal type
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
        case 0:                      // Spinner
            progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
            progThread.start();
            return progDialog;
        case 1:                      // Horizontal
            progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progDialog.setMax(maxBarValue);
            progDialog.setMessage("Dollars in checking account:");
            progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
            progThread.start();
            return progDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Handler on the main (UI) thread that will receive messages from the 
    // second thread and update the progress.

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
            // and update the progress bar.
            int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
            progDialog.setProgress(total);
            if (total <= 0){
                dismissDialog(typeBar);
                progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
            }
        }
    };
}


    // Set current state of thread (use state=ProgressThread.DONE to stop thread)
    public void setState(int state) {
        state=ProgressThread.DONE;
        mState = state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ProgressBar.postInvalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#postInvalidate%28%29) you can try this.

Comment: Cannot function at all.I think this lack something.